# Is there any way to pass parameterized function as an argument in callback function

Tags: c++, esp32, arduino-esp8266

I had to call function as argument but is it possible

```
swichLightOffTimer->setOnTimer(&switchOffLight);
```

How can I call function with parameter as argument

```
swichLightOffTimer2->setOnTimer(switchOffLight2(LIGHT2));

pirSensorTimer->setOnTimer(&pirSensor);
pirSensorTimer->Start();
```

Comment: You could use a lambda (or function) as adapter. However, to make this answerable, the expected signature of the function (pointer) had to be known. Please, [edit] and show what `setOnTimer()` is expecting.